# Global variable set and then reset in Python Canvas

Tags: python, game-loop

Good afternoon,

I'm building out (suppose to be) a relatively simple q & a experiment for a psychology experiment. I'm using Pythons canvas for drawing and painting but have hit a bit of brick wall and a classic update scenario, I think. Here's the code:

```
# Replace with 60000 for 1 minute a question
screen_timeout = 10000
start_time     = clock.time()

# Create a canvas, mouse & keyboard object
canvas         = canvas()
mouse          = mouse()
kb             = keyboard(timeout=0)
question       = '1) Which two chemicals are discussed?'
answer         = ''
show_circle    = False

global circle_clicked
circle_clicked = False

def draw_question_and_answer(c, a):
    c.text('%s<br />(Just start typing; press enter to submit)<br /><br />%s' % (question, a))

def draw_mouse(c, (x, y)):
    c.fixdot(x, y)

def draw_circle(c):
    c['circle'] = Circle(0, 0, 50, fill=True, color='red')

def paint(c, a, s, (x, y)):
    c.clear()
    # show_circle_every(s, 2500)
    # NOTE Drawing order matters here
    if s:
        draw_question_and_answer(c, a)
        draw_circle(c)
        draw_mouse(c, (x, y))
        if (x, y) in c['circle']:
            circle_clicked = True   
    else: 
        draw_question_and_answer(c, a)
    c.show()

def game_loop(c, m, a, s):

    while True:
        if clock.time() - start_time >= screen_timeout:
            break   

        # if clock.time() - start_time >= 2500 and s == False:
        #   s = True

        response, timestamp_kb = kb.get_key()
        (x, y), timestamp_m    = m.get_pos()

        # TODO Extrapolate to function
        if s == False:
            if response == 'return':
                var.gq1 = a
                log.write_vars()
                break

            if response != None and response != 'right shift' and response != 'left shift':
                if response == 'space':
                    a += ' '
                elif response == 'backspace':
                    a = a[:-1]
                else: 
                    a += response
        paint(c, a, s, (x, y))

        # If the user enters the circle it should disappear
        print circle_clicked
        if clock.time() - start_time >= 2500 and circle_clicked == False:
            s = True

game_loop(canvas, mouse, answer, show_circle)
```

What I'm trying to do here is show a red circle every 2.5 seconds and keep the circle there until the users mouse enters the boundary of the circle. In these lines here:

```
if clock.time() - start_time >= 2500 and circle_clicked == False:
    s = True
```

I'm setting the s variable (show) to True to show the circle which works. And in this line:

```
if (x, y) in c['circle']:
    circle_clicked = True
```

if the user enters the circle I'm setting clicked to true. But if I print the values I can see circle_clicked changing from True to back False - How come? Does the loop get it's own version of circle_clicked? If so how?

What am I doing wrong here as I think it's quite a simple problem? Coming from a purely Javascript background also complicates things as I'm trying to learn Python to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your **paint** function to this

```
def paint(c, a, s, (x, y)):
    global circle_clicked
    c.clear()
    # show_circle_every(s, 2500)
    # NOTE Drawing order matters here
    if s:
        draw_question_and_answer(c, a)
        draw_circle(c)
        draw_mouse(c, (x, y))
        if (x, y) in c['circle']:
            circle_clicked = True   
    else: 
        draw_question_and_answer(c, a)
    c.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - can you explain your rationale? Also - am I suppose to keep everything else as is as it didn't work just changing the paint function to what you added

Comment: So I got it to work - so it appears that I need to explicitly class global on any variables that are global that are used in functions to maintain the correct reference then it seems

Comment: Yes, you  find the right approach, same approached I mentioned in my soultion